# Is selecting Data0 really a point of no return?

Tags: needy-streamer-overload

After getting every ending in Needy Streamer Overload, a new save file labeled Data0 appeared on the main menu. Clicking it makes a message appear.

> You will not be able to return. Continue?
>
> | Cancel | OK |

Is this really a point of no return? Will still I be able to reload an old save if I click OK?

[image: "You will not be able to return" prompt]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, selecting Data0 is not a point of no return. You will be able to reload your save file afterwards to get any missing achievements or gallery photos.

> Selecting Data0 will trigger an ending where Ame makes choices without your input. Once the ending is complete you will be able to reload the game and continue your original save files.

Answer (score 2):

When you see that Data 0 savefile it means that you've unlocked every ending in the game, so there shouldn't be much to lose at that point.

Data0 playthrough:

> will automatically run a scenario based on choices that Ame makes herself without your input.

The main purpose of this playthrough is:

> to open the file labeled 'secret.txt' hidden behind the windows

Source, [Gamefaqs](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/pc/305571-needy-streamer-overload/cheats).

Comment: There are still unearned achievements and locked gallery photos

Comment: That message makes me think that this should be a sort of post-game, so I wouldn't risk it if you still have missing achievements.